# JSF datatable/panel display on condition

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a `datatable` I display with some value from database etc.
I only want to render the `datatable` if there is values to display, if not maybe display a message saying there is no values.

I know you can add the `datatable` to a `panelgroup`, example:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{myList > 0}">
```

Is there a better way of doing this? how would i display the message if the `datatable` is not rendered?

using jsf 2.2 and richfaces 4.

thanks

Comment: question downvoted before anyone even said anything, thanks, Ill ask elsewhere.

Comment: What's wrong with going `<h:dataTable ... rendered="#{not empty myList}">` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use opposite conditions for rendering message or result table. For example:

```
<h:outputText value="No payment receipt to display"
    rendered="#{paymentReceiptList.size == 0}"/>
<rich:dataTable id="paymentReceiptTable" var="receipt"
    value="#{paymentReceiptList}" rendered="#{paymentReceiptList.size > 0}" >
```

Or you can display "No result found" info inside `rich:dataTable` using:

```
<f:facet name="noData">
    <h:outputText value="#{msg.noData}" />
</f:facet>
```

Or you can display your message inside `rich:dataTable` using `noDataLabel` attribute of `rich:dataTable`.

Comment: @Vasil Lukach Just for Info. It can be done with an attribute of the datatable itself noDataLabel="message" and we can improve rendered="#{! empty paymentReceiptList}"